# Is there a perfectly accurate way to view SVGs in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, svg

Maybe it's just me.

I spent a couple months learning Javascript just to be able to use D3.js, and enjoyed making fairly complex geometric shapes for intellectual exploration, but then I found a dirty secret.

Even though the math is correct and D3 seems to handle it, **there are NO perfectly accurate SVG viewers**.

For a quick example of this, create two circles with their centres `r * 2` width apart with a radius of `r`.
Zoom in without recalculating the viewport.
Eventually, the circles will either look like they overlap or not touch at all.

### Example with 6 circles, all `r * 2` distance apart.

For reference, these screenshots were taken from Affinity as I could not figure out how to get D3 to do this. To Serif Labs' credit, they did make code changes to make rendering at zoom more accurate, and those changes reduced the space to about 1/4 of what it was.

#### 100%

[image: Circles Example Zoom level 100%]

#### 400%

[image: Circles Example Zoom level 400%]

#### 100000% (centre of the image)

[image: Circles Example Zoom level 100000%]

Comment: It sounds like it might just be that your circle centers aren't in the exact positions you think they are, due to the limits of the representation.

Comment: Why is this tagged as D3? This is an **SVG** issue. Even better: this is a **user agent** issue. Besides that, I'm voting to close it because I can't see a "question".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Edited the title to make the question more clear: Is there a perfectly accurate way to view SVGs in D3.js?

Comment: @joshfindit thanks for editing, but that's my point: D3 is not a library to manipulate SVGs. D3 is a library to manipulate elements based on data, and one can create a dataviz without any SVG (using canvas, HTML etc). Those issues you described (and I'm not doubting it) are SVG issues, or, as I said, maybe browser implementation issues.

Comment: @user2357112: At high zoom levels, the lines actually move around because of the bezier curve rendering for circles not actually producing perfectly round circles. If the math is as simple as basing everything on `r` and `r * 2`, and the numbers are high enough to be accurate (used a math library for this as Javascript does not natively support this precision), then the centres can be reasonably expected to be exact.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Ahh, I see your point. Thanks for the push. I'm not trying to say that D3.js is in the wrong here, but more asking if it's possible for D3.js to render the representation of the math in a visually accurate way. (I only say "SVG" because that's what I'm used to in D3.js, I'm open to Canvas, HTML, etc)

Comment: Let me explain with an oversimplified example: when you say `selection.append("circle").attr("r", 10)`, d3 creates a node like `<circle r="10"></circle>`. That's it. From that point on, it's the user agent problem drawing the circle. If the circle is skewed, or oval, or blurred, or anything else, it's the user agent's problem.

Comment: Browsers use floating point maths, they try to balance accuracy with speed. They are highly unlikely to change their current balance in the way you want.